# SiteMap problem after URL change

Tags: magento2, url, sitemaps

I changed my domain name after a Magento 2 installation, modified the Magento configuration to put the new URL there but the generated sitemap still shows the link of the products with the old URL. I do not understand where to go to modify the URL chosen by the sitemap

Thank you

Comment: Might sound obvious but it wasn't clear from your post, you did regenerate it right?

Comment: Yes I regenerated it and of course emptied the magento cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you opening the sitemap.xml file in your browser and it's still showing the old links?

If so, try incognito or hard refresh the page. Your browser most likely cached the results

Comment: Yes I have tried by emptying the computer cache and especially by directly downloading the .xml file from the ssh. But nothing helps it still regenerates the old URLs. I can't understand why he keeps them. 
The site is running very well on the new domain name.

Comment: Are you positive it's overwriting the sitemap.xml file with the new one?

Comment: Yes thank you it work !